# Bootstrap and Rails, display products side by side

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm trying to display products side by side by groups of three.
But they always display as lists.
I did my bootstrap preset,
I tried float:left, display: inline block but it doesn't work. here is my code:

```html
<% @products.each do |product| %>
  <div class="entry img_back col-xs-10 col-xs-offset-0 col-sm-10 col-sm-offset-0 col-md-9 col-md-offset-0 col-lg-9 col-lg-offset-1">
    <div class="product_img">
      <%= image_tag(product.image_url)%>
    </div>
    <div class="product_description">
      <h3><%= product.title %></h3>
      <%= sanitize(product.description)%>
      <div class="price_line">
        <span class="price"><%=product.price%></span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<%end%>
```

this is my result:

[image]

Comment: Groups of 3 you need `col-*-4` ! where `*` is your desired size (lg, md, sm, xs) !

Comment: why? seems weird cause my image width is 250px, with 80px of margin..

Comment: Bootstrap grid system has 12 columns, 12 / 4 = 3 ! means each product must occupy 4 columns !

Comment: Yeah you was right! It was my fault.. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bootstrap grid system has 12 columns, groups of three means each product must occupy four columns:

```
<div class="row">
    .....
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="entry img_back">
            <!-- HTML here -->
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="entry img_back">
            <!-- HTML here -->
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="entry img_back">
            <!-- HTML here -->
        </div>
    </div>
    ......
</div>
```

**Note:** you need to add `class="img-responsive"` to your images to get a fully responsive layout.

I hope this will help you.

Comment: Is it normal that my elements are not aligned at all with this method?

Comment: I need to see an example ! Could you set up a jsfiddle or just a screenshot?

Comment: yes, I did it already in my answer, as you can see, I transformed my elem-backgrounds to black, and the alignment is not great

Answer (score 0):

Thanks it works well, i did :

```html
  <% @products.each do |product| %>
    <div class="entry col-xs-4 col-xs-offset-0 col-lg-4 col-lg-offset-0">
      <div class="product_img img-responsive">
        <%= image_tag(product.image_url)%>
    </div>
    <div class="product_description">
      <h3><%= product.title %></h3>
        <%= sanitize(product.description)%>
      <div class="price_line">
        <span class="price"><%=product.price%></span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

but it looks weird, my divs are not very well aligned with this method, it looks like that, not centred, not aligned :

[image]